Choose $k$ numbers in the set of $n$ continuous integers, the absolute difference between adjacent numbers is less than or equal to $m$
From the set $S = \{1, 2, 3...n-1, n\}$ containing n positive integers, how many distinct selection schemes are there when choosing k numbers such that they are arranged in ascending order as $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k$ and satisfy the condition $a_2 - a_1 ≤ m, a_3 - a_2 ≤ m, a_4-a_3<=m..., a_k - a_{k-1} ≤ m$?
For example, $n=10, m=2, k=3$: there are $28$ different choices, of which $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{1,3,4\}$ are both correct choices，but $\{2,5,6\}$ is not the correct choice, because $5-2=3 > m$.

What does "its two adjacent numbers" mean?  Same for "its neighboring $2$ numbers".

From S={1,2... n} selects k number.
Suppose the k numbers selected in descending order are a1,a2,... ak, requires a2-a1<=m, a3-a2<=m  ...   ak-ak-1<=m

The idea is to consider the gaps between the chosen numbers. Suppose that the chosen numbers are $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$, arranged in increasing order. Define the numbers $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
x_0&=a_1-1\\
x_i&=a_{i+1}-a_i-1,\qquad i\in \{1,\dots,k-1\}\\
x_k&=n-a_k
\end{align}
$$
So, $x_0$ is the number of unchosen numbers which are smaller than all chosen numbers, $x_i$ is the number of unchosen numbers between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ whenever $1\le i\le k-1$, while $x_k$ is the number of unchosen numbers after $a_k$.
Choosing the set of numbers is exactly the same as choosing the integer values of $x_0,\dots,x_k$, subject to these conditions.
$$
x_0+x_1+\dots+x_k=n-k\\
x_i\ge 0 \quad (0\le i\le k)\\
 \color{#0000AA}{x_i<m\quad (1\le i\le k-1)}
$$
If you ignore the $\color{#0000aa}{x_i<m}$ conditions, then the number of ways to choose $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k$ is $\binom{n}{k}$. This follows from stars and bars; alternatively, it follows because ignoring the gap condition means we are just selecting $k$ numbers from $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
To account for the $\color{#0000aa}{x_i<m}$ conditions, we use stars and bars. First, we  must subtract out all solutions which violate $\color{#0000aa}{x_i<m}$ for some $i\in \{1,\dots,k-1\}$. This is equivalent to counting solutions to
$$
x_0+\dots+x_{i-1}+(x_i-m)+x_{i+1}+\dots+x_k=n-k,
$$
with all variables, including $x_i-m$, constrained to be nonnegative integers. Again, using stars and bars, the number of solutions is $\binom{n-m}k$. You then deal with the double intersections, where two conditions are violated, which is counted by $\binom{n-2m}{k}$, and so on. Using stars and bars, therefore, the number of solutions is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^k\binom{k-1}{j}\binom{n-jm}{k}.
$$

Wow! Just a few hours of posting the question someone came up with a clearer explanation of the algorithm! Thanks so much!!!

but I think $x_0+x_1+..+x_k=n-1$, not $n-k$

@user1315461 Good point. I fixed the mistake. I intended $x_i$ to be the number of unchosen numbers between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$, but I had an off-by-one-error.
